# Unable to login due to presence of special character in my password in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to login into my website by passing username and password paramters in HTTP Request in Jmeter. But I'm unable to login due to presence of special character in my password. So, I really want to know what do i have to do to accept password with special character.

Answer (score 0):

In the parameters table, check encode next to the password with special characters.